# Codeigniter inherit a existing $_SESSION

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am attempting to capture exiting sessions from a NONE codeigniter site, the site has a variable called `$_SESSION['username']` , now when the current user is logged from that site and attempt to visit the codeigniter site the controller will just transfer the current `$_SESSION` to `set_userdata`, so far below is my code but i have no luck trying to `print_r` if its successfully captured, any help would be great!

I am using the `$this->session->set_userdata`.

```
    <?php

    class Pages extends CI_Controller{

        public function view($page = 'home'){



                if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php')){
                        show_404();
                }

        $this->session->set_userdata('CI_Username',$_SESSION['username']);           
        $data['user'] = $this->session->userdata('CI_Username');


                $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

                $this->load->view('templates/header');
                $this->load->view('templates/nav');
                $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');

                print_r($data);

        }

}
```

Comment: Is that other site you mentioned belong to the same server of your website?

Comment: Yes it is, but i cannot get the $_SESSION['username'] value

Comment: Have you tried `print_r($_SESSION);`  or `print_r($this->session->userdata)` instead of `print_r($data)` ? Check if there are values on session.

Comment: Yes i tried bu the $_SESSION['username'] is not there.

Comment: If there is no `$_SESSION['username']` it means that you cannot get the session from the other website. The way you store the codeigniter session has no problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying that, looks like i need to find another way to inherit the existing sessions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get data of sessions, you should try this:

```
$data['user'] = $this->session->userdata('CI_Username');
```

Because

```
$this->session->set_userdata(...);
```

is used to assign value to your session.

Here is the link: [Link](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: Unfortunately still cannot get the $_SESSION['username'] i will update my question code, if you see anything wrong.

Comment: Can you show me your session value when you edit? Please

Comment: Yes i tried , but my goal is getting the existing $_SESSION['username'] declared from another site, but its not passing it on my controller, is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's session mission, you can pass value in $_SESSION['username'], and you can get $_SESSION['username'] in another site.

Comment: If you used $_SESSION['username'], I don't think you need to use `$this->session->userdata('CI_Username');` anymore, because $_SESSION is the same as it.

Answer (score 0):

When set the sessions

```
$sessionoptions = array('username', 'John');

$this->session->set_userdata($sessionoptions);
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data

Make sure on the config.php you have set the session save path correct.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/sessions/';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = TRUE;
```

Set session folder permission 0700.

Then

```
$data['user'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
```

Comment: Yes the session is properly configure, i am trying to get the $_SESSION['username'] declared from a previous none codeigniter site, but cannot get it to display on my controller.

Comment: Dont think you can.